# What is this pattern called (helps avoid type casting)?

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns, oop

Found myself trying to find a link to an official definition of this design pattern which I believe I saw in Go4 but can't seem to find it anywhere.

```
class Processor{
    ProcessParameter(AbstractParameter x){
        x.Process(this);
    }

    ProcessParameter(ParameterA x){
        ... A-specific logic...
    }

    ProcessParameter(ParameterB x){
        ... B-specific logic...
    }
}

abstract class AbstractParameter{
    abstract void Process(Processor p);
}

class ParameterA : AbstractParameter{
    override void Process(Processor p){
        p.ProcessParameter(this);
    }
}

class ParameterB : AbstractParameter{
    override void Process(Processor p){
        p.ProcessParameter(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). The technique is called "double dispatch".

Comment: I liked the first version of your answer better. This _is_ Double Dispatch. The Visitor pattern adds the notion of _multiple_ Visitors (called "Processor" in my example).

Comment: I switched the emphasis since the title asks for the "pattern", and the question refers to GoF.